# how to use a Python function with keyword "self" in arguments

Tags: python, self

i have a function that retrieve a list of stores in Python this functions is called :

```
class LeclercScraper(BaseScraper):
    """
        This class allows scraping of Leclerc Drive website. It is the entry point for dataretrieval.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        LeclercDatabaseHelper = LeclercParser
        super(LeclercScraper, self).__init__('http://www.leclercdrive.fr/', LeclercCrawler, LeclercParser, LeclercDatabaseHelper)


    def get_list_stores(self, code):
        """
            This method gets a list of stores given an area code

            Input :
                - code (string): from '01' to '95'
            Output :
                - stores :
                    [{
                        'name': '...',
                        'url'
                    }]

        """
```

when i try to write `get_list_stores(92)` i get this error :

```
get_list_stores(92)
TypeError: get_list_stores() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

how can you help me with this ?

Comment: Try `self.get_list_stores(92)`. It's like the `this` keyword in Java

Comment: Is this function in a class definition? It should be, but there aren't many contexts where you could actually call `get_list_stores(92)` without a `NameError` if it was in a class definition.

Comment: self is NOT a keyword.

Comment: Yes, like Jim said, self is not a keyword. It could have whatever name you want. `self` is just a convention.

Comment: It looks like it takes a string, and you are passing it an int.  Could that be a problem as well?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If the function is *inside* a class (a method), write it like this:

```
def get_list_stores(self, code):
```

And you have to call it over an instance of the class:

```
ls = LeclercScraper()
ls.get_list_stores(92)
```

If it's outside a class, write it without the `self` parameter:

```
def get_list_stores(code):
```

Now it can be called as a normal function (notice that we're not calling the function over an instance, and it's no longer a method):

```
get_list_stores(92)
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't use "self" arbitrarily - self is recommended to be the first parameter to functions which are written to be methods in classes. In that case, when it is invoked as a method, like in

```
class A(object):
    def get_list_stores(self,  code):
        ...

a = A()
a.get_listscores(92)
```

Python will insert the "self" parameter automatically on the call 
(and it will be the object named "a" in the outer scope)

Outside of class definitions, having a first parameter named "self" does not make
much sense - although, as it is not a keyword it is not an error per se.

In your case, most likely,t he function you are trying to call is defined in class:
you have to call it as an attribute of an instance of the class, and then you 
simply omit the first parameter - just like in the example above.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to use it in the class, access it like this:

```
self.get_listscores(92)
```

If you are trying to access it outside of the class, you need to first create an instance of `LeclercScraper`:

```
x = LeclercScraper()
y = x.get_listscores(92)
```

Also, `self` is not a keyword.  It is simply the name chosen by convention to represent a class instance within itself.

Here's a good reference:

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)